# Country and state field in form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have two select fields(country and state) in "My Account" form for user which are auto populated with countries and state list from countries.js. This works fine
But whenever user opens his account details(like amazon) I want the respective fields to be populated with current values from database (since these are active input fields user can also change the values). I am doing this by echoing values in input field like(see code below)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tgender" name="tgender" value="<?php echo "$trainer_gender"?>" >
```

nter code here

But this doesn't work for country and state. If I am echoing the values in country and state field then dropdown of countries doesn't work(if user wants to change or for first time user)

Comment: those are select fields, so you need to set corresponding option values to be "selected" attribute added during the creation of them in php. You should probably add you php part for the form creation too, but this is how it is done. <option selected>option value</option> will be the selected one and assign it in the loop that you create your select object in php.

Comment: show your code! what have you done exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Values of select boxes are set different compared to text input fields.

What you are searching for is the `selected` attribute of the `<option>` tag (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option).

Wherever you build your selection box for the country/state, you need to iterate over that list, and check if the current iteration value matches the one from the database.

For example:

```
<select name="state">
  <option value=''>SELECT</option>
  <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id, name FROM states');
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
      $selected = ($stateFromDB == $row['name']) ? 'selected' : '';
      echo "<option value='$row[id]' $selected >$row[name]</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
```

You can also select the correct value via Javascript, e.g. by using jQuery:

```
$("#state-list").val("Your State from DB");
```